# Efficient Cassandra DB design to retrieve a summary of time series financial data

Tags: cassandra, time-series, cassandra-2.0, finance, cassandra-3.0

I am looking to use the apache cassandra database to store a time series of 1 minute OHLCV financial data for `~1000` symbols. This will need to be updated in real-time as data is streamed in. All entries where `time>24hr old`are not needed and should be discarded.

Assuming there are 1000 symbols with entries for each minute from the past 24 hrs, the total number of entries will amount to `1000*(60*24) = 1,440,000`.

I am interested in designing this database to efficiency retrieve a slice of all symbols from the past `[30m, 1h, 12h, 24h]` with fast querying times. Ultimately, I need to retrieve the OHLCV that summarises this slice. The resulting output would be `{symbol, FIRST(open), MAX(high), MIN(low), LAST(close), SUM(volume)}` of the slice for each symbol. This essentially summarises the 1m OHLCV entries and creates an `[30m, 1h, 12h, 24h]` OHLCV from the time of the query. E.g. If I want to retrieve the past 1h OHLCV from 1:32pm, the query will give me a 1h OHLCV that represents data from 12:32pm-1:32pm.

What would be a good design to meet these requirements? I am not concerned with the database's memory footprint on the hard drive. The real issue is with fast querying times that is light on cpu and ram.

I have come up with a simple and naive way to store each record with clustering ordered by time:

```
CREATE TABLE symbols ( 
 time timestamp,
 symbol text,
 open double,
 high double,
 low double,
 close double,
 volume double
 PRIMARY KEY (time, symbol)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time DESC);
```

But I am not sure how to select from this to meet my requirements. I would rather design it specifically for my query, and duplicate data if necessary.

Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: A little off-topic but I don't understand what kind of time serie you want to build here. 'open' and 'close' will normally only be updated once in a 24h period. 'high' and 'low' will only change if the price continue to move in the same direction, if the traded instrument moves up in the morning and down in the afternoon it will have the same 'high' price for the rest of the day. And 'volume' is accumulated to start with so you can not do a SUM() on it.

Comment: I am recording OHLC and volume for each 1 minute interval, not for the whole day. The volume traded for each interval is the total for that specific interval. So for a 60 minute snapshot, I would need to find the new OHLC and SUM() the volume from all intervals within the 60 minutes.

Comment: Ok I understand, so the data you're looking at is more granular (trades I presume). One thing before I go, you're using terms (open/close/high/low) that already has a specific meaning in a different way so you might get more people than me a little confused ;)

Comment: The data isn't trades specifically. It's meaning is exactly the same as OHLCV for a 24h period, but on a 1m period. I'll edit the question to make my thoughts more clear

Comment: use cassandra along with spark. use cassandra as primary database and spark as analytic assistant. You will do read/write through cassandra only, but in the backend write scripts to get data into spark and let spark do the computations and push it back to cassandra. Spark has advanced api calls so that it extracts data from cassandra tables and inserts back into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not based on Cassandra, [Axibase Time Series Database](https://axibase.com/docs/atsd/administration/compaction/#results) can be quite relevant to this particular use case. It supports SQL with time-series syntax [extensions](https://axibase.com/docs/atsd/sql/#period) to aggregate data into periods of arbitrary length.

An OHLCV query for a 15-minute window might look as follows:

```
SELECT date_format(datetime, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', 'US/Eastern') AS time, 
  FIRST(t_open.value) AS open, 
  MAX(t_high.value) AS high, 
  MIN(t_low.value) AS low, 
  LAST(t_close.value) AS close, 
  SUM(t_volume.value) AS volume 
FROM stock.open AS t_open
  JOIN stock.high AS t_high
  JOIN stock.low AS t_low
  JOIN stock.close AS t_close  
  JOIN stock.volume AS t_volume  
WHERE t_open.entity = 'ibm'
  AND t_open.datetime >= '2018-03-29T14:32:00Z' AND t_open.datetime < '2018-03-29T15:32:00Z'
GROUP BY PERIOD(15 MINUTE, END_TIME)
  ORDER BY datetime
```

Note the `GROUP BY PERIOD` clause above which does all the work behind the scenes.

Query results:

```
| time                 | open     | high    | low      | close   | volume | 
|----------------------|----------|---------|----------|---------|--------| 
| 2018-03-29 10:32:00  | 151.8    | 152.14  | 151.65   | 152.14  | 85188  | 
| 2018-03-29 10:47:00  | 152.18   | 152.64  | 152      | 152.64  | 88065  | 
| 2018-03-29 11:02:00  | 152.641  | 153.04  | 152.641  | 152.69  | 126511 | 
| 2018-03-29 11:17:00  | 152.68   | 152.75  | 152.43   | 152.51  | 104068 |
```

You can use a Type 4 [JDBC driver](https://github.com/axibase/atsd-jdbc), API clients or just [curl](https://axibase.com/docs/atsd/sql/api.html#curl-query-example) to run these queries.

I'm using sample 1-minute data for the above example which you can download from Kibot as described in these [compression tests](https://axibase.com/docs/atsd/administration/compaction/).

Also, ATSD supports [scheduled queries](https://axibase.com/docs/atsd/sql/scheduled-sql.html) to materialize minutely data into OHLCV bars of longer duration, say for long-term retention.

Disclaimer: I work for Axibase.

Comment: This looks like it will suit my use case very well. I'll look into this in more depth. Thanks